# Dúvida sobre como trabalhar com (getViewportHeight())

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou com um problema.
Tenho uma biblioteca Javascript que cria um slider adpatável na horizontal.
O que preciso é que a altura do bloco tenha uma altura específica conforme o `viewport` do browser.
Por exemplo:
Se o browser tiver `600px`, o bloco terá `600px - 50px`, ficando com altura de `550px`
Se o browser tiver `768px`, o bloco teria `718px`.
Descobri na biblioteca o seguinte fragmento de código

```
slider.viewport.height(getViewportHeight());
```

Acredito que teria que trabalhar com isso.
Alguém pode dar uma idéia ou indicar um caminho?

Grato.

Answer (score 0):

Se esse método `slider.viewport.height()` é o que seta o tamanho do seu slider, porque não usar `slider.viewport.height(window.innerHeight - 50)` ?